# Leaflet Draw 0.4.9 control not working with Leaflet 1.1.0?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I created a very minimal codepen, but I am getting an error when trying to create the draw control.

See: https://codepen.io/DrYSG/pen/QgmVZg

I assume it is something simple that I doing wrong. But I looked at the CDN I am using , and I see nothing obvious:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.9/leaflet.draw-src.js

These are the errors I am seeing in the console:

```
Util.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property segmentsIntersect, object is not extensible
    at Object.extend (Util.js:15)
    at LineUtil.Intersect.js:6
    at EditToolbar.Delete.js:145 extend @ Util.js:15 (anonymous) @ LineUtil.Intersect.js:6 (anonymous) @ EditToolbar.Delete.js:145 pen.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor
    at pen.js:11
```

---

```
var map = L.map("root").setView([42, -71], 7);

L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Leaflet.draw is not working with Leaflet 1.1.0 . It has been reported. As long as [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/739) is not closed, consider the problem still there.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to setup this codepen to show an issue with mensuration (distance measures) but as you can see this is also a issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/735#issuecomment-313232837

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can't comment until I have more reputation.

Leaflet.Draw `0.4.10` has been released that limits the ceiling version of Leaflet to `1.0.x` rather than `1.1.x`. Leaflet 1.1.x introduced ES6 and Rollup which Leaflet.Draw was not prepared for, and that is being actively pursued to be resolved.